# You will not use a little water. You will use little water.?

Tags: meaning

You will not  use a little water. 
You will use little water.

Both are same meaning and they are all ok?

Comment: The two have very different meanings, and the first sentence is not something a native speaker would ever say. What is it you want to express? NB you might find in future that [ell.se] is a better place to look for answers.

Answer (score 1):

"How much water should I use?"
"Just use a little water."

"In the desert there is little water to be found."

Comment: You've provided good examples, but you haven't explained *why* they should be used - preferably citing an authoritative reference. See [answer]. You can [edit] your answer to provide the missing detail, but note that you're responding to a poorly worded question (which is why it's on hold). The Help Centre says "Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which ... are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem." I can recommend **taking the [Tour]** :-)